# Graph generation using Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I would like to generate undirected graphs without self-loops using `networkx` library using the following idea: in the beginning we have two nodes and one edge that is connecting them. Then on the next iterations we create new node and connect it with two edges to random chosen nodes of the graph. So then next iteration will be 3 nodes and three edges (circle), then 4 nodes and 5 edges, 5 nodes and 7 edges, etc.

Here is my approach:

```
import random
import networkx as nx
    
def generateGraph(n):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_node(0)
    G.add_node(1)
    G.add_edge(0, 1)
    nodes = []
    
    while G.number_of_nodes() < n:
        new_node = G.number_of_nodes()
        new_edge = G.number_of_edges()
        G.add_node(new_node)
        destination = random.choice(new_node)
        nodes.append(destination)
        G.add_edge(new_node, new_edge)
        G.add_edge(node, new_edge)
    return G
```

What am I missing here and how can I change my approach? The problem that there are only n nodes and n+1 edges using this model but it should be n nodes and +2 edges(after 5 nodes). Thank you

Comment: What is the result of your code?  What is wrong with it? What do you want the requested change in approach to achieve?

Comment: I have edited my question and tried to explain it there.

Comment: So add an extra edge between two unconnected nodes at the end so that your edge counts is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this should follow your algorithm

```
def generate_graph(n):
    G = nx.Graph([ (0, 1) ])  # put list of edges

    for n in range(2, n):
        # take two nodes randomly
        nodes_to_take = random.sample(list(G.nodes), 2)
        G.add_edges_from([   # connect new node 'n' with two chosen nodes from graph
            (n, nodes_to_take[0]), (n, nodes_to_take[1])
        ])

    return G
```

Result:

```
gr = generate_graph(7)
nx.draw_networkx(gr)
```

[image]